# How do I seamlessly manage 2 identities on bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket

I have a personal account on bitbucket which I maintain for my personal projects. Currently, my company uses bitbucket also and in order to checkout code I need to use my ssh key. When I tried using the same key as my personal account, bitbucket rightfully rejected it complaining the key already exists. How can I use the same key for both accounts or is there a workaround for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you take a look at [github-keygen](https://github.com/dolmen/github-keygen)

It is similar to the gist you have linked to but a more complete approach as well as having better documentation on the settings created.

At the very least, it links to some good materials on ssh, encryption and configurations :-)

Comment: Looking at github-keygen though, I think this is specific for github. Probably be good to fork and generalize to code so that it can be used for both.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: This link which is for github works too for bitbucket:

https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996

**The summary:**

Create 2 keys, then add them to your ssh using `ssh-add` and your are good to go, then log into both accounts and add they keys to your account. Editing your `~/.ssh/config` is also important for the guide to work. Please read through all the comments too.